# Нажимаю на кнопку сообщение не выводит?

Tags: python, telebot

При нажатии на кнопку нечего не выводит

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('ТОКЕН')

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
    butt1 = types.KeyboardButton('ПОЛУЧИТЬ ДЕНЬГИ')
    butt2 = types.KeyboardButton('‍КАНАЛ')

    markup.add(butt1, butt2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, {0.first_name} что-бы получить деньги нажми на кнопку'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)
    if message.text == 'ПОЛУЧИТЬ ДЕНЬГИ':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чтобы получить ахч'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)
    elif message.text == '‍КАНАЛ':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'АХХАХАХА лох'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)

bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Comment: У вас обработчик только для команды start. А то, что в `message.text` поместите в обработчик по тексту

Comment: как ?..........................

Comment: Например, создайте еще одну функцию с декоратором `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])` и в нее перенесите код с условиями. Т.е. при запуске бота, будет вызван start, вы в нем напишите приветствие и создадите клавиатуру с кнопками. Когда юзер нажмет на одну из кнопок будет послано сообщение с текстом из кнопки и сработает функция-обработчик с новым декоратором, а там будет проверка в условии

Answer (score -1):

Для обработки обычного текста (не команд) нужно использовать это:

```
@client.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def TextHandler(message):
```